# Access SharePoint online using client object model- Forbidden error

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-clientobject

I tried to Create a new list item using client object model. I have created an asp.net application to do the task. It works if I pass the URL of SharePoint server which is installed in my machine.
But if I give my SharePoint online URL it is not working as below code shows. I get "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. " error.
Any idea?

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/SitePages/");
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
newItem["Title"] = result.City;
newItem["Body"] = result.State;
newItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: where did you passed the login credentials ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are trying to get a Context object from SharePoint Online you have to put in the right `Credentials`, as for SharePoint Online you should use the [SharePointOnlineCredentials Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx)

A possible Authentication Method can be look like this:

```
private void AutheticateO365(string url, string password, string userName)
{
   Context = new ClientContext(url);
   var passWord = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
   Context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);
   var web = Context.Web;
   Context.Load(web);
   Context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'SharePointOnlineCredentials' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; which version of the SharePoint dll's are you using ? SharePoint Online is always Version 16 you can use for it Version 15 and 16. But SharePoint Online is SharePoint 2013 and not 2010 like you tagged this question

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you just have to supply your login credentials and it should work:

```
clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
```

You'll need to including System.Net:

```
using System.Net;
```